# Throw error if property added to a frozen global object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

Using [Object.freeze()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) prevents editing an object:

```
> const obj = { a: 1 };
> Object.freeze(obj);
> obj.b = 2;
> obj
{ a: 1 }
```

However, only in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) is an error thrown when attempting to add a property:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot add property hi, object is not extensible
```

**Is there a way to create an immutable global object, where an error is thrown if code tries to edit the object?**

Comment: The designers consciously decided to only throw an error in strict mode (presumably for backward compatibility reasons).  Not much you can do about that.  FYI, I hope you realize the object is immutable either way, in sloppy mode it's just that the error is just silent.

Comment: Run your app in strict mode?